# ERROR: localhost redirected you too many times USING PHP

Tags: php

Good morning, I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm developing an evaluation system for teacher and  I have encountered this problem.

This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

MY CODE:

```
<?php
```

////DATABASE CONNECTION HERE!
session_start();

```
include("connection.php");
include("functions.php");
    
    
    //CHECKING THE BUTTON IF IS IT CLICK!
    
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if(!empty(['submit'])){
                if(!empty(['statement'])){
                    
                    $statement1 = $_POST['statement1'];
                    $statement2 = $_POST['statement2'];
                    $statement3 = $_POST['statement3'];
                    $statement4 = $_POST['statement4'];
                    $statement5 = $_POST['statement5'];
                    $statement6 = $_POST['statement6'];
                    
                    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO results VALUES('','$statement1', '$statement2', '$statement3', '$statement4', '$statement5', '$statement6')");
    
                    if($result){
                        echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert("YOUR RESPONSE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED. THANK YOU!") </script>';
                        
                    }
                }
                else{ 
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert("SUBMIT YOUR RESPONSE") </script>';
                    }
            }       
            else{
                echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert(" PLEASE CLICK ONE RADIO BUTTON PER QUESTIONS! </script>';
                }
        }   
    header("Location: evaluation.php");
    die;
```

?>

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: ???`header("Location: evaluation.php");`???  What are you trying to accomplish?!?

Comment: This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 2

Comment: You forgot `$_POST` in if statement

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm trying to redirect the page to index page which is the TEACHER LIST PAGE so I could evaluate other teachers.

Comment: This problem come when both page redirect to each other. Check evaluation.php file and comment `header()` function and try

Comment: @UttamNath THANKYOU IT WORKED! but how could redirect my page to teachers page if i'm going to remove header?

Comment: @Awel check my answer bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- header() function returns error like ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS that change page name.php to some url like below.

```
header("Location: /index.php");
```

Or

```
header("Location: ./index.php");
```

Or

```
header("Location: ../application/index.php");
```

Comment: @Awel: not to beat a dead horse ... but I think you might be taking the wrong approach with "redirects".  A web app is typically a series of "requests" and "responses".  For example: 1) A user browses to your landing page ("requests" the file "index.php").  2) The server responds by doing a mysql query of all teachers, and responds with an HTML "form".  3) The user gets the form, selects a teacher, and clicks [Submit]. 4) This is another "request" to the server. Perhaps to file "evaluation.php";  5) The server responds with the evaluation form.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `header("Location: evaluation.php");`. You're inadvertently redirecting to yourself, infinitely.

Remove that statement.

TYPICAL ("CORRECT") BEHAVIOR:

1. User browses to your first page, e.g. "index.php".
2. You might do a database lookup to generate some HTML, or it might be static HTML.
3. In any case, the page contains an [HTML form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), and has a "Submit" button.
4. The user fills in the form, and clicks the button.
5. This calls your *NEXT* PHP page.
6. And so on...

It sounds like maybe you want your "first page" to query the database and present a list of teachers. Specifically, PHP will 1) query the database, 2) generate an HTML form, 3) which containins an HTML table, 4) one row per teacher.

The user selects a teacher (e.g. by clicking a radio button for the teacher on that row), and clicks "submit".

The "second page" might be an "evaluation form" for the chosen teacher.  The user clicks "submit" on the second form when he's completed the evaluation.

The "third" (and final) PHP page might be an HTML message that says "Thank you for submitting this evaluation".

No "redirects".  Just series of HTML forms, generated one at a time.